# Почему не выводится среднее значение с дробными знаками в этой программе? (Переменная sr)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Задачи
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
            int pow = n1 * n2 * n3;
            Double sr = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
            Console.WriteLine(n1 + "+" + n2 + "+" + n3 + "=" + sum);
            Console.WriteLine(n1 + "*" + n2 + "*" + n3 + "=" + pow);
            Console.WriteLine("({0}+{1}+{2})/3={3:#.###}", n1, n2, n3, sr);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пересдача экзамена?

Comment: потому что если все операнды целочисленные, деление так же будет целочисленным.

Answer (score 2):

В этом объявлении

```
Double sr = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
```

выражение инициализации имеет целочисленный тип, так как переменные `n1`, `n2` и `n3` объявлены как имеющие тип `int`, а потому никаких дробных частей у него нет.

Вы могли бы написать, к примеру

```
Double sr = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3.0;
```

или

```
Double sr = ( double )(n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
```

или, как подсказывают,

```
Double sr = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3d;
```

Символы `d` и `D` в C# служат суффиксами для обозначения числовых литералов с плавающей запятой двойной точности

Comment: или `(n1 + n2 + n3) / 3d`